# Why do I have to attach IE in WatiN when running test on a server via Cruise Control service

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, watin

I have been doing the following for the longest time and it works without any issues when I initiate it:

```cs
[Test]
public void GoToMethod()
{
    // Pre: ie = new IE();

    NewEmployeePage page = ie.Page<NewEmployeePage>();
    page.GoTo(); // which launches IE
}

[Test]
public void AssertionMethod()
{
    NewEmployeePage page = ie.Page<NewEmployeePage>();
    Assert.That(page.FirstNameTextBox.Text, Is.EqualTo("John"));
}
```

The assertion method normally still has an ie that is intantiated.  When the AssertionMethod executes, NewEmployeePage will just assume the currently open browser.  Now when the AssertionMethod executes via a CruiseControl service (running under a service account), ie is null.  I finally got around this issue by doing the following:

```cs
[Test]
public void AssertionMethod()
{
    string url = ie.Url;
    ie = IE.Attach<IE>(url);

    NewEmployeePage page = ie.Page<NewEmployeePage>();
    Assert.That(page.FirstNameTextBox.Text, Is.EqualTo("John"));
}
```

I'm just wondering why I have to do this when my tests are ran by a CruiseControl service?